# Can longitude and latitude change?

Tags: geolocation

I'm working on a GeoTargeting application. I'm curious if longitude and latitude of a point on the earth can change?

If you know the exact position of the statue of liberty how sure is it that longitude and latitude will stay the same.

Does it change according to the season, time in the year, or slowly over time

Comment: i might be just a stupid german - but postal codes for which nation(s)...?

Comment: If you use C# they change sometimes, but not often (in Belgium, that is), but using Java the change is much more frequent.

Comment: Ok I try it again. I fear to get an answer to your question you have to specify it a bit.

Comment: @GVS: they might change for the reason posted in my answer..

Comment: @GvS: I thought it was the other way round? Perhaps you are thinking of POSTAL CODE?

Comment: @MIKE: I know, but why is this question tagged with C#?

Comment: Latitude + Longitude + Vector

Comment: Asking one question, editing out a relevant part that people used in their answers, and then patronizing them in comments for not reading the question is pretty special.

Comment: Dude, @TEgeril. I just looked at the question, i was driving to home. These other dudes keep editing the freaking question and changing it around.. I didnt.

Comment: @unknown: I'm sure the original question mentions postal codes, (and has some strange tags). But you tell aric to "Read the question" if his answer mentions the postal codes. I'm pretty sure Aric tried to answered the question before YOU edited it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude) to the rescue:

> The surface layer of the Earth, the
>   lithosphere, is broken up into several
>   tectonic plates. Each plate moves in a
>   different direction, at speeds of
>   about 50 to 100 mm per year. As a
>   result, for example, the longitudinal
>   difference between a point on the
>   equator in Uganda (on the African
>   Plate) and a point on the equator in
>   Ecuador (on the South American Plate)
>   is increasing by about 0.0014
>   arcseconds per year.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the map projection variables you use. Currently [WGS-84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WGS_84) is used mostly.

The same point can have different coordinates depending on the variables. They do not differ a lot, I remember the difference between EUR-50 (or something like that) and WGS-84 was at most 50 meters or something.

Answer (score 6):

You're tangentially referring to geodetics, which is the science of modelling (representing) the shape of the earth. So while a physical location may not change, the datum (model) used by a geodetic coordinate system will change, fortunately this does not happen frequently.

In North America [NAD83](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Datum) is the mostly widely used datum, which replaced NAD27.

Did I mention that Geographic Information Systems (GIS) was my foray into software development?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Zip codes get split all the time, and doing so would move the center of the zip code to a new location.

Comment: What s longitude or latitude got to do with zip code ? Definition of longitude: the angular distance between a point on any meridian and the prime meridian at Greenwich. How this will change? I understand zip code changes but how this affects it s location relative to Greenwich?

Comment: "What s longitude or latitude got to do with zip code": Nothing. The question was about the lng/lat of a particular postal code, whether it can change or not.

Comment: But I think the question has been edited.. it does not mention postal codes anymore..

Comment: Yes, the original question asked if the longitude / latitude of a postal code (In American English, a Zip Code) could ever change.

Answer (score 3):

47.554 always equals 47.554

But if the shape of the earth changes or you are using different methods of calculations (there are plenty) or if the input data changes in precision or if if your compiler treats floating point differently..

you'll end up in different long/lat

Comment: Are you saying that long/lat to 3 decimal places will be a consistent reliable coordinate?

Comment: @chris No see the accepted answer... You might geolocate a city where its center is at 1.23456 and years later be at 1.23457.

Comment: ah i was hoping you had done the math and that 3 decimal places would be  safe :)